# Hive calling MAP reduce for simple select query

Tags: hive

I created a table in hive and loaded data into it. when executing simple " select * from " it is calling map reduce.

Actually simple select statement without where clause is just cat of HDFS file and should not execute MAP REDUCE.

Can you please suggest what to do for not calling MAP reduce for simple select

Comment: Have you used SERDE?

Comment: what is SERDE? I am sorry I am new to this. Can you please let me know about it?

Comment: What kind of data you have loaded?

Comment: Structred data. It is the data from oracle tables.

Answer (score 0):

way 1) hive>**set hive.fetch.task.conversion=minimal**  in your hive session and then trigger select * operation in your hive session to avoid mapreduce call

way 2) add the following property in hive-site configuration to avoid Mapreduce call  for all the sessions

```
<property>
 <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion</name>
 <value>minimal</value>
 <description></description>
</property>
```